# lenny to squeeze upgrade, partitions disapper

Tags: debian-squeeze, udev

I have an RealPrivateServer on OVH provider, I have completes the upgrade, but after all packages were upgraded, the system for some reason don't generate the disk devices in /dev properly. I had the system mounted in /dev/sda1 but the swap was not mounted. In fact there were no /dev/sda or /dev/uba at all. 
I'm fix this problem creating the missing devices and mount swa. So I create the devices
my partitons:

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor #blocks name
180 0 503808 uba
180 1 497983 uba1
8 0 20971520 sda
8 1 20479969 sda1
```

Create the devices accordingly to your values above, then you can enable the swap disk:

```
mknod /dev/uba b 180 0
mknod /dev/uba1 b 180 1
swapon -a
mknod /dev/sda b 8 0
mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1
```

But the problem is on system reboot, the devices disappear!
I don't know why, but i suspect about udev fault.

how can I verify that udev recreates right devices on boot time?